# The complexity order of regret (especially in online reinforcement learning)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, time-complexity, online-learning, regret

In online reinforcement learning theory, how to judge the complexity order of regret, if there are two or more terms in there?

For example, the state space is $X$, the action space is $A$, the episode number is $K$, and the horizon number is $H$. If we have an algorithm with regret $R_K=2X^2A H \ln K \ln H + 3XAH^2\ln K$.

How can I decide the order of this algorithm? Should we look at which term is dominant with respect to the episode number $K$ or total steps $T=HK$? Then it might be $O(XAH^2\ln K)$

Or also consider the relationship with the state and action space? Then it might be $O(X^2AH^2\ln K)$, here I choose the highest order of each variable in both terms.

Comment: Do you mean the computational/algorithmic complexity to compute the regret?

Comment: Yeah. To briefly understand the meanings of parameters, you can consider that there are $K$ different policies $\pi_k, k =1,\cdots, K$ with episodes going on. For each policy, the agent will make decisions according to the policy for $H$ steps, and get his rewards and feedback on these steps. And then update the policy to the next episode. Then the total interaction steps will be $T=HK$.

Regret is the difference between the cumulative reward of the $K$ episodes according to the online updated policies and that according to an unknown optimal static policy.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your algorithm to loop over $K$ policies (or episodes), for $H$ steps, on each state and action pairs (where $X=|\mathcal S|$ and $A=|\mathcal A|$ denote the size of the state and action spaces; assuming them to be discrete for simplicity.)

If so, and assuming an algorithm $R_K=2X^2AH \ln K\ln H + 3XA H^2 \ln K$ which makes such amount of steps *both* in the worst and best case (I'll clarify that later), it's computational complexity is about:
$$\begin{align}
O(R_K) &= O(2X^2AH \ln K\ln H + 3XA H^2) \\
       &= O(X^2AH \ln K\ln H + XA H^2) & (1) \\ 
       &= O\big(XAH \ln K (X\ln H + H)\big) & (2) \\
       &= O\big(n^3\ln n\ (n\ln n + n)\big) & (3) \\
       &= O\big(n^4\ln^2 n + n^4\ln n\big) \\
       &= O(n^4\ln^2 n) & (4)\\
       &< O(n^5) & (5)
\end{align}$$

**Explaination.** In line (1) I discard the constants $2$ and $3$ because they don't affect the complexity. Then, in line (2) I group by the common factor $XAH\ln K$. Next in (3), I rewrite $n=XAH\ln K$ note that this is not mathematically exact but for the purpose of computational complexity you can assume $n$ to be your overall input size, i.e. the complexity of the algo $R_K$ is a function of $n$. In line (4) the term $n^4\ln^2 n$ dominates $n^4\ln n$, so you can remove the latter. Lastly, your final complexity is $O(n^4\ln^2 n)$ but if you're not sure of its scale you can further bound with a degree-five function, i.e. $n^4\ln^2 n$ doesn't grow as fast as $n^5$.

(Last point: if your algo behaves the same both in the worst $O(\cdot)$ and best $\Omega(\cdot)$ case, your *average complexity* is $\Theta(n^4\ln^2 n)$.)